# Change values on second level of multidimensional array while looping

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I have a hw assignment that I'd like to finish. I have most of it done but I am getting stuck in one place. I have a two dimensional loop of strings in C which represent students and their grades.

My goal is to be able to have a user  display the grades, then be able to update them. I structured the array to show the name of the students and the grade at the end after two space characters. I managed to get to the point where I was able to locate the students in the hard coded array. I've also gotten to the point where I can isolate the last array value (the grade) and display it. My issue is when I try to updated that value to a new value. The way I have the code now when replacing the grade it overwrites the entire value along with the student name.

**EDIT:**
I wanted to update, I beleived that the current output was overwriting the student's array value with just the updated grade, but it actually is just updating the first value in the array with the updated grade value.

I have tried strcat to try and concatenate the name of the student and the updated grade. Just to see what happens. It looked something like

```c
strcat(updated_grade, student_info[j])
```

I tried experimenting with using the different pointers along with my code to no avail.

```c
int DisplaystudentInformation()
{
  // Welcome Message shows after successful login
  printf("%s\n", "Welcome professor. Below are all student grades");

  // Hard code array to hold student information
  char student_info[5][10] =
  {
    "Jim  A",
    "Tom  C",
    "Ben  C",
    "Alice  D",
    "Ruby  F",
  };

  // Initialize i to use to loop through array
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int t = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(student_info)/sizeof(student_info[0]); i++)
  {
    // Used multiple spaces to get rid of dangling new line
    printf("%s    \n", student_info[i]);
  }

  // Character for reading if faculty wants to adjust grades
  char adjust_grades[2];

  printf("%s", "Adjust grades for students? Please Type y to adjust, or n to exit: ");
  scanf("%s", adjust_grades);

  // Check if adjust grades is Y
  // Using == as the correct assign operator
  if (strcmp(adjust_grades, "y") == 0 || strcmp(adjust_grades, "Y") == 0)
  {
    //Set up vars for adjusting grades
    char student_to_adjust[10];
    char temp_name_input[3];

    // Get name of student
    printf("%s", "Please enter students name: \n");
    scanf("%s", student_to_adjust);

    // Create a temp name to copy the first three letters of a student's name
    strncpy(temp_name_input, student_to_adjust, 3);

    // Terminate null characters manually
    if (strlen(student_to_adjust) == 5 || strlen(student_to_adjust) == 4)
    {
      temp_name_input[strlen(temp_name_input) - 3] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
      temp_name_input[strlen(temp_name_input) - 3] = '\0';
    }


    // Temp char to serve as copied string, still using the first three letters of the student name
    char temp_student_name[3];

    for (j = 0; j < sizeof(student_info)/sizeof(student_info[0]); j++)
    {

      strncpy(temp_student_name, student_info[j], 3);

      // Found Student and will edit grade
      if(strcmp(temp_student_name, temp_name_input) == 0)
      {
        // Use this to adjust grades
        printf("%s", "\nStudent found. \n");

        // Determine the size of the array and adjust the position of the array spot.
        if (strlen(student_info[j]) == 6)
        {
          printf("\nCurrent Grade: %c \n", student_info[j][5]);

          //New grade character
          char new_grade[1];

          printf("%s", "Enter new grade: \n");
          scanf("%s", new_grade);

          student_info[j][6] =  *new_grade;


          // Show all the students grades along with the updated grade
          for (t = 0; t < sizeof(student_info)/sizeof(student_info[0]); t++)
          {
            printf("%s    \n", student_info[t]);
          }
        }

        break;
      }
    }


  }
  else if (strcmp(adjust_grades, "n") == 0 || strcmp(adjust_grades, "N") == 0) // Option to log out if the user is not adjusting anything
  {
    printf("%s", "\nLogging you out \n");
    exit(0);
  }
  else // Logs out if invalid entry it put in
  {
    printf("%s", "\nInvalid input, logging out. \n");
    exit(0);
  }

}
```

I am expecting something like:

```
Jim  A
Tom  C
Ben  C
Alice  D
Ruby  F
```

But what I am currently getting is:

```
F
Jim  A
Tom  C
Ben  CF
Alice  D
Ruby  F
```

Comment: `char adjust_grades[1];` is too small for a _string_ of   letter and a _null character_.  Why so small?

Comment: @chux adjust_grades is only to indicate that the user wants to adjust the grades. I'm not saying the way I'm doing that is right or wrong, but that works in the context of the program I'm making. That's not where I'm having an issue.

Comment: Still too small - only big enough for `""`, not `"y"`.  Rest of code is irrelevant until that is fixed.

Comment: @chux I would disagree seeing as that portion of my code works how I expect it to and errors out how I expect it to. I did adjust it to make it a little larger and it does not solve my overall issue.

Comment: Don't write `int i = NULL;` — use `int i = 0;`.  Only use `NULL` when referring to a null pointer.  On some (many?) systems, `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` or thereabouts, and assigning a pointer to an integer elicits compiler warnings.

Comment: As already pointed out, you cannot reliably use `char adjust_grades[1];` to read a string (`%s`).  It may appear to work.  That is an (un)lucky coincidence.  You will be forcing `scanf()` to write outside the bounds of the array, which is dangerous (undefined behaviour).  It might seem to work; it cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Appreciate the explanation. I updated it to make the array larger and it still does work. I'm still trying to solve my overall issue. Also changed the nulls as you pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand what you're saying. Solving all the issues should be the goal. I apologize if I sound like an idiot. I actually changed the array size for the update_grade and that solved some of my issue. Now the array is updating as I'd like to. I just need to work through the first. I think it might be an issue with staring at this screen for too long. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several buffer overruns which are stomping over memory. The behaviour of your program, even if correct, will not be predictable until they are fixed.

The first is `char adjust_grades[1];`, which needs to be at least length 2 to contain 1 character and the NULL terminator.

The second is `char temp_name_input[3];`, which again, doesn't have room for the NULL terminator.

Next is `strlen(temp_name_input)`, which is called (twice) before `temp_name_input` is a valid string, so the result is bogus. Check carefully what `strncpy` does - it does **not** generate a terminated string if your source string has more than 3 characters, which is true in your case.

Next is `char temp_student_name[3];`, which again is not long enough.

Your memory is well and truly hosed at this point in the program, so all bets are off. There are likely more problems, but start with these and you'll be well on your way to something closer to done.

Comment: Thanks for the all your help. I looked over the issues which you mentioned. I was able to run the program as expected. Thanks again for the help!